# Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, браузер, прокрутка

Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Во время прокрутки происходит сильное дерганье блока то вверх то вниз. Как исправить?

```js
$(function() {
    var $hor = $("#horizontal");
    $("body").css('padding-bottom', $(window).width()*2);
    var delta = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        var width = $(window).width();
        var lim = $hor.position().top - (delta) - ($(window).height() - $hor.outerHeight()) / 2;
        delta = Math.min(Math.max(top - lim, 0), width * 2);

        $(".horizontal:first", $hor).css({left : delta});
        $(".horizontal:last", $hor).css({left : -(width*2 - delta)});
        $("body").css({'padding-top': delta, 'padding-bottom': width*2 - delta});
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    height: 500px;
}
#horizontal {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 250px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
#horizontal .horizontal .h_blockquote {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test</p>
<div id="horizontal">
    <div class="horizontal">
        <div class="h_blockquote">
            <div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal">
        <div class="h_blockquote">
            <div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить? Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: в консоль посмотри ошибки

Comment: и что не пашет? в фоксе тоже лажа полная.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, зачем Вы откатили правку? участник сделал правильную правку, поставил правильно отступы, сделал код более читаемым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исправить нельзя, потому что вначале происходит движение по `event scroll` и только потом срабатывает функция на `scroll`. (Вначале страница поднемается, а потом добавляется `padding` к `bady`).
Как вариант, отлавливать прокрутку ролика мышки:
(*в коде надо только правельно выставить границы*)

```js
var boo = true;
var delta = 10;
$("body").css('height', "6000px");
var $hor = $("#horizontal");
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      boo = false;
      $("body").css("overflow", "inherit");
      if ($(document).scrollTop() < 250 && !boo && (delta > 0 - $(".h_blockquote_wrap").width())) {
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        delta -= 10;
        $(".horizontal").css({
          left: delta + "px"
        });
        if (delta < 0 - $(".h_blockquote_wrap").width()) {
          $("body").css("overflow", "inherit");
          boo = true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      boo = true;
      $("body").css("overflow", "inherit");
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250 && boo && (delta < $("#horizontal").width())) {
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
        delta += 10;
        $(".horizontal").css({
          left: delta + "px"
        });
        if (delta > $("#horizontal").width()) {
          $("body").css("overflow", "inherit");
          boo = false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  height: 500px;
}
#horizontal {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 250px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
.horizontal {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.h_blockquote {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test</p>
<div id="horizontal">
  <div class="horizontal">
    <div class="h_blockquote_wrap">Скрипт некорректно работает в браузере Internet Explorer. Как исправить?</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="foo">test</p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: теперь и в хроме сломалось :-)

Comment: @Grundy у меня работает....

Comment: У меня тоже поломалось =(

Comment: @Grundy раскройте "на всю страницу"...

Comment: @C.Raf.T, какая-то проблема с прокруткой начинается при достижении красного прямоугольника

Comment: @Grundy когда доходит до div с текстом, пока не прокрутете весь текст до исчезновения, overflow будет hidden, так же и в другую сторону..

Comment: @C.Raf.T, ну вот у меня как раз с прокруткой проблемы и возникают :-)

Comment: @Grundy не знаю... ((

Comment: @LADYX может я чего-то не понемаю... http://www.picshare.ru/view/7639862/

Comment: @LADYX строчка с body только для того, чтобы показать, что страница прокручвается. точку захода в функцию можно менять взависимости от контента на странице. Просто здесь функция обязывает прокрутить всю строку либо вправо либо влево. Можно добавить, к примеру , что только когда курсор находиться в пределах div'а прокрутки, вертикальный скроллинг изчезает...

Comment: @LADYX убевать никого не надо. Я дал только один из вариантов + абсолютно сырой... Насчет плагина,  надо посмотреть, лично не знаком..